How to test a femto ammeter?
I am making a device that will measure extremely low currents. 10 fA as the value of LSB. How to create a reference current source?

Femtoamps? Have you considered using a field mill? Measurement speed becomes an issue.

@glen_geek I haven't, care to elaborate?

How many bits of resolution will your meter have?  Will the meter use a shunt resistor, and if so what value?

I bet you could use SQUIDs for this. Not that that's a practical method, but you probably could.

What is the total current range in femto-amps that you are trying to measure?

I don't know for sure, but probably something like 10fA to 1nA

The easiest way is just to pull your your credit card and buy an electrometer instrument that is calibrated and will source or measure what you need. Maybe in the $10k-20k range new, if you can find one.
You can get op-amps with 0.1fA typical input bias current at room temperature and 1GΩ/10GΩ/100GΩ 1% resistors, and try making a Howland style current source. At 100GΩ, 1fA is a relatively healthy 100uV voltage.
Of course the devil is in the details on something like this, and it might be cheaper to buy the commercial unit, if it exists and your time is valued at first-world prices. Special techniques, shielding, guards, ultra-low leakage PTFE capacitors etc.
But if you're making the measurement device, maybe you already have a good skill set in the area.

Thank you. Trying my best

wow what an amazing piece of equipment, 0.01fA..... i don't even know what engineers/scientist have a use for something like this.  many nano-Amperes in photodiodes is about as low as i've ever had to work with.

@rohmeooo I think the author of the question said 10 fA. Not 0.01 fA. And that's the least significant digit so it may be allowed single-sigma noise near that level. In modern photodiode detectors from a good manufacturer like Hamamatsu and in dice form (not packaged), surrounded by wire-bonded dice electronics and cooled reasonably well, may allow clear evidence of photon "flocking' noise at around 0.5 fA.

@periblepsis Yes, that instrument is gross overkill but even things like the SRS CS580 (source with 100fA resolution) are still pretty $$$.

At these currents, a small capacitor, ideally PTFE or polystyrene, fed with a known rate of ramp, makes a very good source.
I = CdV/dt
To get a known, constant, rate of ramp, use an integrator fed from a constant signal.
Alternatively, avoiding an integrator, a calculable but non-constant ramp can be sourced from a capacitor, running down through a resistor. Charge them to a voltage and let them run down.
Of course, any change in the voltage of the current measurement input will cause an error. For a good current measurement input, the input impedance will be small. You can minimise the effect of input impedance by making your source voltage swing large, and using a very small capacitor.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Various possibilities for generating the ramp, with different component count, noise performance, constancy. Note that the constant current source for the op-amp integrator would normally simply be a resistor from a voltage, as the -ve input is a virtual ground.

the reverse is probably easier: Make any current of the desired order of magnitude via a voltage source and large series impedance (e.g. reverse biased diode). Run this current through the femto ammeter and into a trans impedance amplifier with a known good capacitor. The TIA ramp will tell you what the actual current was and consequently, which value the femto ammeter was calibrated with.

@tobalt That needs a known good TIA. Good capacitors are probably easier to come by, and better.

You just need to run the test once without the current, to subtract the TIA input current. Input current stability is probably on the order of a few fA over reasonable times for off the shelf MOSFET opamps. The greatest unknown is the capacitor either way.

@tobalt I feel no need to add to my answer. Please feel free to create your own answer if you feel those here are not putting your view across.

I = V / R
Get a voltage source and a resistor that are accurate enough for your test.
Connect them so they run current through your meter.  If your meter has input resistance, then make sure to factor that into the calculation.
Note that since you need femtoamps either the resistor will be very large, or the test voltage will be very small.  Getting a tera-ohm resistor is probably going to be hard.  So instead divide the voltage in several stages using smaller value resistors.
For a voltage reference you can use a precision reference chip like the ADR4525BRZ (which is 0.02% accurate out of the box).  You can then divide it down by a factor of 1,000,000,000 using three pairs of 0.01% resistors like Stackpole RNCF series to get a 2nV reference.  From there use a resistor to get various femto-amp currents.  Note that thermal noise is going to be a problem.  You need filtering in your meter, but you can also add a low leakage film capacitor across the 2nV source to reduce noise at that point.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

With the resistor ladder the current is sensitive to the exact value of the offset voltage. (In principle the voltage source could be reversed to check this). Also- OP hasn't said what he mean by "test" so we don't know whether he wants 10% or .01% accuracy.

I had 1E9 and 1E10 resistors mounted in a box, BNC female on one side BNC male on the other. I think they were 1%, from Vishay, glass housing. Connect known voltage source one side, measured with DVM, other side connected to femtoammeter.
High value resistors should be cleaned with alcohol and then not handled so having them installed in a box is convenient.

You might consider using a non-contact signal source to measure femto-amp currents. I had suggested a field mill (used to measure static electric fields), but a simpler version might be adapted for your calibration: one that doesn't require rotating parts.
Construct a simple capacitor, whose one plate connects to your femto-ammeter. The other plate is driven from a low-frequency AC voltage source. If you wish, a guard ring can be added to reduce fringe plate coupling.

 If plate separation is small enough, capacitance from "input" plate to the grounded Faraday shield might be made insignificant.
